# Is the KeyVaultClient method GetSecret() safe?

Tags: azure, security, azure-keyvault

I'm working with Azure Key Vault and I'm testing the "Managed Identities" for Azure Resource. Long story short: with this feature we can easily access to a KeyVault secrets from (e.g.) VM, App Service... I wrote this simple code:

```
    private void GetKeyVaultSecrets()
    {

        AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

        var akvCallback = new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback);
        var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(akvCallback);

        var secret = keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mySecret").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string superSecret = secret.Value;
    }
```

And I'm able to access my "Secret" **without any kind of Authorization**. Is it safe? Am I missing something? It looks so strange that with those 7 lines of code you have access to all your secrets. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this on a service with a system-assigned Managed Identity, here's what actually happens (example for App Service, VM is slightly different):

1. Your app reads IDENTITY_ENDPOINT and IDENTITY_HEADER environment variables
2. HTTP call to IDENTITY_ENDPOINT using the IDENTITY_HEADER as authentication

   - This endpoint cannot be called from the outside, only from within the instance.
   - Its port is also random
3. In the call, your app specifies it wants a token for Key Vault (resource https://vault.azure.net)
4. The Managed Identity endpoint uses the certificate it has created to authenticate to Azure Active Directory with the Client Credentials flow
5. Azure AD verifies the request and issues a token
6. Managed Identity endpoint returns the token to your app
7. KeyVaultClient uses the token to authorize the call to Key Vault

On Virtual Machines, the Instance Metadata Service is used to get tokens.

The main thing to understand is that any process running on the instance itself is capable of getting tokens from the Managed Identity.
Though if you were to get malicious code running on your instance,
other approaches could be in trouble as well :)

If you run that code locally, it can work as well.
AzureServiceTokenProvider also attempts Visual Studio authentication as well as Azure CLI authentication.
So if you are logged in to e.g. AZ CLI, it is able to get an access token for your user to Azure Key Vault and access it.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?context=azure%2Factive-directory%2Fmanaged-identities-azure-resources%2Fcontext%2Fmsi-context&tabs=dotnet#rest-protocol-examples

Example request done in VMs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad#access-data

Comment: So key concept here is "AzureServiceTokenProvider also attempts Visual Studio authentication". What you are saying is that the token can be issued because Visual Studio Account is connected to the Azure Account. This really makes sense. I gave it a try in another VS (with a disconnected account) and it wasn't able to get the KeyVault value. So here is the "magic": visual studio is passing the credentials. Is it correct?

Comment: Yeah, it's using the refresh token that VS has to get a token for Key Vault. This token will contain your user's objectId, so as long as there is an access policy on the Key Vault that allows that user to read secrets, the call will pass.